# Windows XP Batch File Date to file name

Tags: windows, batch-file, embedded

I am currently using the below code to return a date format from a XP embedded machine, it is a fairly basic version of XP, the below code returns the correct format on a windows 7 machine (10-02-2015) but on the XP machine it returns (Tue), how can I modify the code to return the correct format, without changing the XP time format on the machine

```
Set timestamp=%DATE:/=-%
```

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19799236/388389

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date format includes the day-of-week at the beginning in many environments - use:

```
set DT=%DATE:/=-%
set timestamp=%DT:~4%
```

to set timestamp the way is on your Win7 environment; however, this approach is not exactly portable, just be aware.

**EDIT**

This will reorder the date and time to something that sorts properly ... and it does happen to also be the order used in Europe:

```
set DT=%DATE:/=-%
set timestamp=%DT:~10,4%-%DT:~4,5%
```

keeping in mind, this *still* isn't portable across systems.

**EDIT**

Whoop, you wanted UK, which *isn't* the same as other places - that would be:

```
set timestamp=%DT:~7,3%%DT:~4,3%%DT:~10,4%
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, this now puts the date in, which is exactly what I want, just one quick question, it puts the date in USA format MM-DD-YYYY can it be converted to UK format DD-MM-YYYY, if possible